# Is there an official/unofficial way to program Unity scripts in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unity-game-engine

I'd really prefer to use python, but Unity only supports C#, UnityScript (similar to JavaScript) and Boo. Is there an official way to use python (ideally 3.x) instead, or an unofficial patch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to use Python, although it is unofficial. See [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/86461-Python-interpreter-in-Unity).

Comment: Please include all information needed to understand the answer in the answer itself. As written, this would be more appropriate as a comment than an answer.