# Is there an official way to program Unity scripts in python?

Tags: python, unity-game-engine

I'd really prefer to use python, but Unity only supports C#, JavaScript and Boo. Is there an official way to use python (ideally 3.x) instead, or an unofficial patch?

Comment: Or maybe you can try blender game engine

Answer (score 0):

if you searched on stack you would have found the answer: [Is there an official/unofficial way to program Unity scripts in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782269/is-there-an-official-unofficial-way-to-program-unity-scripts-in-python)

anyways there is an unofficial implementation: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/86461-Python-interpreter-in-Unity

Comment: It's better to flag the question as a _duplicate_ rather than posting a link to it here. Also, consider summarising the Unity3D link in case it goes to the broken link gods